# Reference standard app builder lightning components in the code

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to create standard lightning components that are visible in App Builder (for example Activities) inside a custom lightning component the same way we can create nested custom components? Something like this:

```
<aura:component>
    <c:Activities/>
</aura:component>
```

[image: Lightning App Builder Standard Components]

I checked the /auradocs/reference.app, but didn't find any reference to Activities standard component

Comment: @martin I didn't find any reference to these components (I am particularly interested in Activities) in /auradocs/reference.app